# Create eclipse project from svn when folder name in SVN is src/java/com

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

In my SVN java source files are under src/java/com/... location. When I create the project in Eclipse I get the package java.com.... but files in there have defined package location as com.something.something., without java name. So it makes all project invalid. If I try to re factor the package name I losing connection with SVN, cannot update , see changes and so on. Changing package name in each file is not an option. This is big application running in production. So actually the question is how I can make Eclipse project to be in sync with SVN and still make it compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in your classpath you referring to the src directory as the source directory.  Change it to be src/java/com.

i.e

```
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/java/com" including="**/*.java"/>
```

Or you can change it from the UI,
Right click project -> Build Path -> 
Configure Build Path -> Click "Source" tab -> 
Click "src" folder -> Click Edit -> Change it to src/java/com

Edit: You might need to remove the src folder then add a new one.  Put the check only next to the one src folder you want.  Or just edit it from the .classpath file.

Comment: When I'm trying to do it via GUI and change it to src/java/com I get the message : The folder 'YouProj/src/java' already exists. When I modify the classpath directly the package line of the java file still indication an error saying:The declared package "com.xxx.yyy" does not match the expected package "java.xxx.yyy"

Comment: Ahh, I wonder why.  Click remove, and then Click add and drill down to src/java/com and check next to com.

Comment: Make sure you do save the classpath, and clean your workspace Project -> Clean -> (clean all) Ok

Comment: This is something to do with eclipse update this time. After refreshing it several time it seems ok. The only comment when I add a new directory via GUI I need to delete the existent one. Thank you very much

Comment: I had to rebuild my Maven project using "clean eclipse:eclipse" Then refresh the project.

Comment: @OrbitingEden -  clean eclipse:eclipse doesn't rebuild your Maven project,  it just generates your Eclipse files from the Maven POM.  The OP does not directly mention Maven,  but I agree it's good idea to re-run eclipse:eclipse if you have classpath issues with a Maven project.